# How do I convert a 3 by 3 single channel Mat to a 1 by 3 triple channel array in OpenCV?

Tags: c, opencv

I have a 3 by 3 rotation matrix, created with the header `cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1)`. This is the matrix I get from calling cvRodrigues2. I want to rotate several points stored in an array of length N with 3 channels. To do this rotation I call `cvMul(rotation, points)`, but this requires that the rotation matrix be an array. I therfore need to convert it to a `cvCreateMat(3, 1, CV_32FC3)`. Is there any way to do this in openCV (in C, if it makes any difference).

Answer (score 1):

Using cvReshape ([link to documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html#reshape)). The second example is very alike to what you want (you just have to adapt the number of rows and channels).